# jwt token, interop dotnet core and dotnet classic

Tags: oauth-2.0, .net-core, jwt, owin

Sadly, documentation on that stuff is hard to get by.

I am a little in a bind in that I have a system which gets a new dotnetcore based API now but I can for now not replace the main system or the security handling it has.

In the old system we generate tokens using the /token endpoint of the OWIN API (which since then ahs been not ported to dotnet core).

We use an OAuthAuthorizationServer that has the following options:

```
new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
    Provider = new AppOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider("OBB"),
    RefreshTokenProvider = new AppOAuthBearerRefreshProvider(),
}
```

The machine config has validateionkey and decryptionkey and is set to use
validation="HMACSHA384" decryption="3DES"

This works fine and is using a hard coded machine key in the web.config for signing. Yeah, something to replace - around dotnet core 2.2 in 2019 as it looks like, when we move that whole thing to a proper oauth server.

I now need to use that token in dotnet core. I think I have the right libraries by using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer, and the token is quite obviously a JWT token. I may be wrong, though.

I am trying to decode it but I end up getting nowhere - all calls return invalid_token.

I set up the services with:

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateActor = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        ValidateTokenReplay = false,
        // Specify the key used to sign the token:
        //IssuerSigningKey = descryptionkey,
        //RequireSignedTokens = false,
    };
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I seem to be unable to find any documentation onw how to get a token issued in dotnet "proper" accepted in dotnet core.

I need to validate that token properly, and extract the one information in it (the id).

Answer (score 0):

I use JWT with this configuration, maybe this will help you.

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                                   {
                                       options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                                       options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                                   }
                                  )
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidAudience = appSettings["JwtAudience"],
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = appSettings["JwtIssuer"],
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(appSettings["JwtSigningKey"]))
                    };
                });
```

In addition, the header key is Authorization with a value formatted as Bearer xxx where xxx is the JWT.